# Smarty and PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, smarty

Im using Smarty and PHP to create a simple blog-like CMS. The problem i'm having is that i can't seem to be able to start a session.

I have an init.php file with the following:

```
<?php
 session_start();

 // Mudar a path do PHP para podermos fazer include das 
 // bibliotecas mais facilmente


 set_include_path(".:./lib");

 // Fazer include do MDB2

 require_once ('MDB2.php');
    (...)
    require_once("Smarty.class.php");

    $smarty = new Smarty;
```

which is called in every file like this:

```
<?php
 require_once("common/init.php");
```

but whenever i try to retrieve session parameters it fails, so i assume the session is not starting correctly.
Any hints???

Comment: What error do you get and what is the code youre using to get session params?

Comment: Consider removing this question as you admitted in comments below you've fixed it. Alternatively, include your fix so other programmers can see it.

Answer (score 0):

at first you can create function link init and call that function,
but your way isn't bad. and must be work. (see frameworks...) 
complete your question with errors

Comment: well, thank you for your fast awnser but i allready fixed the problem.

Comment: the session was starting ok, i just wasnt setting the session parameters the right way!!!